# User profile CCK integer fields

Tags: 7, entities, users

I've built a custom user profile. All the values I want to display are outputting correctly, bar one. The only difference between the fields is the one that doesn't render is an integer, whereas the ones that do render are all varchars.

Is there a specific way of grabbing the value of the field if its an int?

I'm using something like the following:

```
function render_element(&$element) {
  if (is_array($element)) {
    show($element);
    return drupal_render($element[0]);
  }
}
```

And then outputting them with this:

```
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
render_element($user_profile['field_phone']); //varchar
render_element($user_profile['field_number']); //integer
```